# My program returns 1 after Sleep() if I change a tcp socket to non blocking in a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, winsock

I have a thread that accepts client connections and makes the client sockets non blocking.

```
    for(char Index = 0; Index < MAX_CLIENTS; ++Index)
    {
        if(ClientSockets[Index] == INVALID_SOCKET)
        { 
            accept(ClientSockets[Index], (sockaddr *)&Address, &AddressSize);
            unsigned long iMode = 1;
            if(ioctlsocket(ClientSockets[Index], FIONBIO, &iMode) != NO_ERROR)
            {
                 Error("Making client socket unblocking has failed.\n");
            }

        }
    }
```

In the main thread I receieve packets from the clients.

In the main thread after I execute Sleep() the program returns 1 and ends.

The only thing that I found to work was removing ioctlsocket from the thread that accepts clients.

Comment: Why are you calling accept on invalid sockets?

Comment: @SergeyA I've initialized all sockets to INVALID_SOCKET so it means it's available.

Comment: You can't do that. `accept` should be called on valid sockets which are created and listened to.

Comment: @SergeyA I was looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code) example. I realize that my error was that I wasn't using accept correctly but I think that initializing sockets to INVALID_SOCKET is correct.

Comment: @vk123 sorry to highjack this thread, but your question about `Watch` window was closed while I was typing an answer. Could you please re-post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are using `accept()` incorrectly.

The 1st parameter of `accept()` is an input-only parameter, specifying which **listening socket** to accept a pending client connection for.  That parameter is not an output parameter, like you are trying to treat it as.

You are passing `ClientSockets[Index]` to the 1st parameter `accept()`.  But `ClientSockets[Index]` is set to `INVALID_SOCKET`.  That will make `accept()` fail, but you are ignoring that error.  You need to pass in the **listening socket** that you created earlier with `socket()` instead.

You are not assigning the *return value* of `accept()` to `ClientSockets[Index]`, so it remains set to `INVALID_SOCKET`.  You are then passing that to the 1st parameter of `ioctlsocket()`, which will fail.  You do check that error, but you are not reporting WHY it failed, otherwise you would have known that it is failing with an error code of `WSAENOTSOCK` (10038) due to being passed an invalid socket.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
for(char Index = 0; Index < MAX_CLIENTS; ++Index)
{
    if (ClientSockets[Index] == INVALID_SOCKET)
    { 
        AddressSize = sizeof(Address);
        ClientSockets[Index] = accept(serverSocket, (sockaddr *)&Address, &AddressSize);
        if (ClientSockets[Index] != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            unsigned long iMode = 1;
            if (ioctlsocket(ClientSockets[Index], FIONBIO, &iMode) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                Error("Making client socket unblocking has failed.\n");
                closesocket(ClientSockets[Index]);
                ClientSockets[Index] = INVALID_SOCKET;
                continue;
            }
            // use ClientSockets[Index] as needed ...
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
AddressSize = sizeof(Address);
SOCKET clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (sockaddr *)&Address, &AddressSize);
if (clientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    unsigned long iMode = 1;
    if (ioctlsocket(clientSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        Error("Making client socket unblocking has failed.\n");
        closesocket(clientSocket);
    }
    else
    {
        int Index;
        for(Index = 0; Index < MAX_CLIENTS; ++Index)
        {
            if (ClientSockets[Index] == INVALID_SOCKET)
                break;
        }
        if (Index == MAX_CLIENTS)
        {
            Error("No room for client socket.\n");
            closesocket(clientSocket);
        }
        else
        {
            ClientSockets[Index] = clientSocket;
            // use clientSocket as needed ...
        }
    }
}
```